# java scanner blocks at .next() when it shouldn't

Tags: java, network-programming, java.util.scanner, inputstream, outputstream

I'm creating a simple Server/Client application. The Server wraps the `socket.getInputStream()` in a `Scanner`. Client takes user input from `System.in` and sends it to the Server with a `PrintWriter`. The server evaluates `scanner.hasNext()` to true, but it blocks at the following `scanner.next()` call. As per the javadocs:

> This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

well.. how does this make any sense? **EDIT:** it is worth noting that when the client terminates, the server now proceeds with the call to `scanner.next()`. Bonus question: the Client instanciates `PrintWriter` with the `autoFlush` parameter as `true`, yet I am required to flush after each call to `.write()`. Why? Here's an MCV of my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MCVServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1337);
        Scanner fromClient = new Scanner(server.accept().getInputStream());
        while (fromClient.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("server heard something: ");
            System.out.println(fromClient.next());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MCVClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1337);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while(true) {
            output.write(input.next());
            output.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of methods next() and hasNext() works as expected. The method hasNext will only return false after it reaches the end of the stream. The method next() will block in case it still didn't reach the end of the stream or it's waiting for input.

The bonus question is also a simple one. As per documentation of PrintWriter class:

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output. These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character.

So, in order to use autoflushing, you need to replace the write method with println:

```
while (true) {
        output.println(input.next());
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Since the stream is `System.in`, it can never reach end of stream, right? But why is `.next()` waiting for input?? There is something in the stream.

Comment: On the client-side, because of the way System.in is implemented (which is a BufferedInputStream), needs to read a '\n' character in order to flush its buffer to the Scanner object.

Answer (score 1):

1. A scanner.hasNext() reads until the *beginning* of the next token can be detected. This does not imply that the entire token has been read or received. But scanner.next() must read all of the token; hence it may block.
2. Autoflush is only effective after calls to methods println, printf or format.

Comment: If the beginning of the 'next token' has been detected, it must mean that one token has been ended, why doens't `.next()` receive that? Do you mean that it doesn't imply that the NEXT token has been received?

Answer (score 0):

Use NextLine() instead of Next()

Comment: NextLine is going to force to read the whole line and not just words. That may be cause the Block. Also, replace the line: `code`while (fromClient.hasNext()) {}`code` with `code`while (true) {}`code` in the server so it will keep reading.